# Passing Data to Custom CollectionView Cell (Static Data for all cells) SWIFT 2

Tags: swift

So I have a collectionView in a viewcontroller. I have a variable var user = User! which stores the current selected user (FYI I'm using Parse). I want to pass variable to the custom cell.

```
extension SentViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return cards.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(Storyboard.CellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SentCardCollectionViewCell

        cell.card = self.cards[indexPath.item]
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.user = user

        return cell

    }


}
```

Now, my problem is that when I pass the variable user to the variable user in custom collection view cell, I get an object that repeats 3 times. i.e.: the same variable gets passed over, but it is multiplied 3 times.

Any idea how to solve this? I have a feeling that it has something to do with the indexPath. Anyone have solutions?

Comment: How many items are in the `cards` array?

Comment: The cards are like posts. So it depends on how many cards people have posted. The app fetches the cards from Parse and stores them in this variable 'cards'. In this particular case, there were 5 cards in the array. But when the data gets passed over to the cell, there are 3. And the 3 are merged into 1 object. i.e.: From collectionview controller it is "jKhbgI24wS" and when it gets to the cell, it become "jKhbgI24wS" "jKhbgI24wS" "jKhbgI24wS" and the object count is only 1.